# combine two columns to eliminate duplicating rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently in a situation where I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
          id  tp    dt        amt
0          1   CR  2017    94678.0
1          1   CR  2018    13508.0
2          1   DR  2017    78671.0
3          1   DR  2018    13797.0
4          2   CR  2017   111417.0
5          2   CR  2018    21479.0
6          2   DR  2017    95266.0
7          2   DR  2018     1864.0
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to combine value of the two columns, tp and dt, and use it as a column name for amt to potentially get rid of multiple row that has the same id. In short, it should look something like the following

```
          id     CR2017   CR2018   DR2017  DR2018
0          1    94678.0  13508.0  78671.0  13797.0
1          2   111417.0  21479.0  95266.0   1864.0
```

I'm wondering if this is possible? I have been toying around with reset_index, set_index, and pivot_table for an hour now but still no luck
Thanks in advance, helps would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with joined columns and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df = df.set_index(['id', df['tp'] + df['dt'].astype(str)])['amt'].unstack().reset_index()
print (df)
   id    CR2017   CR2018   DR2017   DR2018
0   1   94678.0  13508.0  78671.0  13797.0
1   2  111417.0  21479.0  95266.0   1864.0
```

Or create new column:

```
df['new'] = df['tp'] + df['dt'].astype(str)
df = df.set_index(['id', 'new'])['amt'].unstack().rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
   id    CR2017   CR2018   DR2017   DR2018
0   1   94678.0  13508.0  78671.0  13797.0
1   2  111417.0  21479.0  95266.0   1864.0
```

But if get:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

it means there are duplicated `id` with joine pairs like:

```
print (df)
   id  tp    dt       amt
0   1  CR  2017   94678.0 <-dupe 1 CR 2017
0   1  CR  2017   10000.0 <-dupe 1 CR 2017
1   1  CR  2018   13508.0
2   1  DR  2017   78671.0
3   1  DR  2018   13797.0
4   2  CR  2017  111417.0
5   2  CR  2018   21479.0
6   2  DR  2017   95266.0
7   2  DR  2018    1864.0
```

solutions are aggreagtion - by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + aggreagte function like `mean`, `sum` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['id', df['tp'] + df['dt'].astype(str)])['amt'].mean().unstack().reset_index()
```

Or [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with default `aggfunc='mean'`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='id',columns=df['tp'] + df['dt'].astype(str), values= 'amt').reset_index()
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['tpdt'] = df['tp'].astype(str) + df['dt'].astype(str)
del df['tp']
del df['dt']
df = df.groupby(['id','tpdt'],as_index=False).sum()
df = df.reset_index().pivot(columns='tpdt', index='id', values='amt')
```

Adding some explanation.
You first create a column that concatenates the values in dt and tp.
Then delete those individual columns as you dont need them.
Post that you do a groupby on id and tpdt and it will sum the amt values for unique pairs of tp and dt.
Post that you can pivot it by tpdt to make it as column header.
You may even explore unstack function for the same.

Comment: At least a one line explanation is expected to earn upvotes

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use all in one with: [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with default `aggfunc` `numpy.mean` with [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [rename_axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index='id', columns = df.tp.astype(str).str.cat(df.dt.astype(str)), values="amt").reset_index(col_level=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

> Output:

```
    id  CR2017     CR2018    DR2017     DR2018
0   1   94678.0    13508.0   78671.0    13797.0
1   2   111417.0   21479.0   95266.0    1864.0
```